# Refactoring in VSCode with Dart not working

Tags: dart, visual-studio-code

I just started working with flutter and I am unable to refactor dart/flutter in VSCode.

I am running VSCode on MacOSX and installed VSCode as per the flutter documentation, installed the dart and flutter plugins.
flutter doctor shows no issues.

The app I am creating runs fine on simulator and devices.

When trying to rename a property, using the refactor shortcut, no option to rename is available.
When trying to rename a class, I get 'No refactorings available'

I can't believe this kind of refactoring would not be available.

What am I missing in my setup? Any suggestions on what I can check, change in VSCode?

Comment: It's been a while since I posted this question. It was probably a configuration issue on my part. Later updates on the dart/flutter plugins resolved this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Highlight property or class name and click on **Rename Symbol**
[image]

Answer (score 17):

If you mean refactorings like `Wrap with Container`, press `Ctrl+.`

Earlier button called "Refactor" in context menu was available, but it isn't now, and `Ctrl+Shift+R` doesn't help. So you can use my advice.

Also reinstalling VSCode helped me to get back the "Refactor" button to the context menu

Comment: Just making it clear its Ctrl key and Dot  key (Don't press + key)

Answer (score 3):

Disabling the dart LSP analyzer will bring back the refactor back to the context menu.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As per below document, I don't see those options available as yet in VSCode plugin.
https://dartcode.org/docs/refactorings-and-code-fixes/

https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/issues/548

Comment: It is working but not showing options like Extract Widget, please help

Comment: for Extract Widget, first select property, then click in refactor, then it will show Extract Widget.

Answer (score 0):

Highlight property or class name and use `F2` to rename.

If refactoring in Flutter/Dart is not working, try disabling other extensions. Sometimes another extension can interfere with refactoring using Flutter/Dart extensions. At least it did in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling the VS code is the best solution for my case  ....

Answer (score 0):

First select the code you want to rename and Refactor, then press F2 to rename after that just press Shift + Enter to refactor
[you can see your Refactor View here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RP53a.png)

then just press Apply

Answer (score 0):

For me downgrading to an older release of the VSCode Flutter extension solved the problem.

Comment: what version exactly did you downgrade to? and what version were you at before?